# contact page in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Now iam working in wordpress to modify new template.now i need to do contact page in that theme for this i have tried this link [wordpress](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/)

my doubt is where i need to put this coding,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <header class="entry-header">
          <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">
          <?php the_content(); ?>

          <p>FORM CODE GOES HERE</p>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

      </article><!-- #post -->

  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
```

Comment: Which method in the link are you attempting to use?

Comment: Create a template using this code and create a empty contact page in WordPress and then assign your new template to contact page.

Comment: in contact us page do u see form code goes here that i need to display

Answer (score 0):

This code has nothing to do with a contact form this i just a basic page template code.

They are showing how to create a custom form but you won't need it just use [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) or you can search for many options available in the plugin directory.

Create a form and just use the shortcode that it generates on your contact us page and you won't need to use the code above.

Comment: the link you mentioned in your question is not required in this method.

that is if you want to create a completely custom solution but since there are some great plugins available that won't be required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Contact Form 7, you would put the code into a template like this (after you've already set it up in your WP Admin):

```
  <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <header class="entry-header">
      <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">
      <?php the_content(); ?>

      <p><?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?></p>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

  </article><!-- #post -->
```

via: http://contactform7.com/faq/can-i-embed-a-contact-form-into-my-template-file/

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to include custom code to your WordPress theme, because you'll lose the opportunity to get updates to the theme with new WordPress releases.
I recommend you to use plugins, there are many of amazing Contact Form plugins are out there, like [WordPress Contact Form Slider](http://wordpresscontactform.com)

In this case you don't need to code anything, just configure the plugin and/or use a simple shortcode to include it to a specified page.